# SMS Broadcast receiver is only toasting when new SMS received

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-toast

I have implemented A Broadcast receiver to read Incoming SMS and execute some task when new SMS is received. It is I have used `Toast` make sure the receiver is working. It is always toasting the new message perfectly when it is received, but failing to do anything else.

```
public class SMSListener  extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static String TAG ="SMSListener";

static Excecuter excecuter;
StaticPaymentManager manager;
private SharedPreferences preferences;//1 TK

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    wl.acquire();
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
    for(int i=0; i<pdus.length; i++){
        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String message = "Sender : " + smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress()
                + "Email From: " + smsMessage.getEmailFrom()
                + "Emal Body: " + smsMessage.getEmailBody()
                + "Display message body: " + smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody()
                + "Time in millisecond: " + smsMessage.getTimestampMillis()
                + "Message: " + smsMessage.getMessageBody();
        excecuter.onSMSReceived(message,context);
        Log.e("SMSRECEIVED",message);//These are not even printing
        Log.d("SMSRECEIVED",message);//These are not even printing
        Log.w("SMSRECEIVED",message);//These are not even printing
        Toast.makeText(context, "My Message Receivedddf: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//But Toast is working fine.
        //Log.e("SMSRECEIVED",message);
        try {
            if (manager==null)manager = new StaticPaymentManager(context);
            manager.enqueuePayment(smsMessage.getMessageBody());
        }catch (Exception e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        wl.release();
    }

}

public static void bindExecutor(Excecuter excecuter){
    SMSListener.excecuter=excecuter;
}
```

}

I have tried to at least print the SMS on the log, but it is not even logging. What can be the problem?

Comment: This is kind of bug in android, sometimes the log doesn't print, but if your toast is printing then your code is fine. Try adding log inside your StaticPaymentManager class and see if you're getting data there

Comment: Maybe try selecting "No Filters" in the Logcat panel

Comment: I have tried updating UI, and Adding Log In various places, Nothing is working. I have tried updating UI on MainActivity with excecutor interface and placed some toast there too. again toasts are working but UI not updated..